# Is there a way to apply wilcoxon test grouped by site?

Tags: r, pairwise.wilcox.test, grouped-list

I want to use Wilcoxon 2-sided test for two treatments across multiple groups, i.e. there is a before and after treatment (Conc) for each of several sample sites. I want to split the dataset into a list by Site then apply the test so i can have an output for each Site individually, however, i am having trouble setting this up as a function that can repeat.

I have a number of sites (Site) and two levels of treatment (Scenario), with resulting scores (Conc):

```
'data.frame':   7344 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Site        : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ Scenario    : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ Conc        : num  4.7727 0.055 0.0552 0.055 0.055 ...
```

there are multiple Conc data points (~60) within each Site/Scenario combination. The reason i chose a Wilcoxon test is primarily because i have slightly uneven sample numbers between treatments (Scenario) for each Site.

When i use this code for the entire dataset i get a sensible result:

```
t1 <- wilcox.test(Conc ~ Scenario, data = data.frame)
t1
```

However, this code doesn't apply the test for each site individually.

I have looked looked at all similar examples i could find (on SO and elsewhere) and this is the best code i could come up with:

```
t2 = data.frame %>% group_by(Site) %>% do(tidy(wilcox.test(Conc~Scenario, data=data.frame), na.rm=TRUE, equal.var=FALSE))
t2
```

this code is giving me an output for each site but all test outputs are the same, even the p value:

```
# A tibble: 107 x 5
# Groups:   Site [107]
   Site     statistic p.value method                                      alternative
   <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                                             <chr>      
 1 A         6145702   0.690 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction two.sided  
 2 B         6145702   0.690 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction two.sided  
 3 C         6145702   0.690 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction two.sided  
 4 D         6145702   0.690 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction two.sided  
 5 E         6145702   0.690 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction two.sided  
 6 F         6145702   0.690 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction two.sided
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
thanks for your help

Comment: You could try `lapply(split(data.frame, data.frame$Site), function(x) wilcox.test(Conc ~ Scenario, data = x))` to get a list of Wilcox tests across all your sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED 21/08/2020 to more closely mirror your data**

Here's a solution with `dplyr` and `purrr` **EDITED to include `broom::tidy` results...**

```
# 'data.frame': 5626 obs. of 3 variables: 
# $ Site.Year: Factor w/ 3 levels "Baffle Creek at Newton Road_2018_2019",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 
# $ Scenario : chr "FF_Total" "FF_Total" "FF_Total" "FF_Total" ... 
# $ PAF : num 4.77 4.77 4.77 4.77 4.77

set.seed(2020)

Site.Year <- rep(c("Baffle Creek at Newton Road_2018_2019", 
                   "Baffle Creek at Newton Road_2017_2018", 
                   "Baffle Creek at Newton Road_2019_2020"), 50)
Scenario <- rep_len(c(rep("FF_Total", 4), rep("Not_FF_Total", 4)), 150)
PAF <- rnorm(150, mean = 2.5, sd = 1)

DailyPAF_long <- data.frame(Site.Year, Scenario, PAF)

DailyPAF_long$Site.Year <- factor(DailyPAF_long$Site.Year)
# str(DailyPAF_long)
# wilcox.test(PAF ~ Scenario, data = DailyPAF_long)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DailyPAF_long %>% 
  base::split(Site.Year) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ wilcox.test(PAF ~ Scenario, data = .)) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(~ broom::tidy(.)) 

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   statistic p.value method                       alternative
#>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                        <chr>      
#> 1       361  0.355  Wilcoxon rank sum exact test two.sided  
#> 2       219  0.0723 Wilcoxon rank sum exact test two.sided  
#> 3       380  0.195  Wilcoxon rank sum exact test two.sided
```

Comment: hi Chuck thanks so much for your answer! I am trying your code but I keep getting the error  object 'Site' not found... do you think I need to convert any of the variables to character?

'data.frame': 5626 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Site: Factor w/ 3 levels "A",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Scenario : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","N": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Score      : num  4.77 4.77 4.77 4.77 4.77 ...

Comment: I've rebooted R out of desperation and it still doesn't work..

Comment: No factors will work.  May I see the exact command you're running please?  It is very likely simply a typo in the command from the error message generated.

Comment: 'data.frame': 5626 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Site.Year: Factor w/ 3 levels "Baffle Creek at Newton Road_2018_2019",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Scenario : chr  "FF_Total" "FF_Total" "FF_Total" "FF_Total" ...
 $ PAF      : num  4.77 4.77 4.77 4.77 4.77 ...

Comment: DailyPAF_long %>% 
  split(Site.Year) %>% 
  map(~ wilcox.test(PAF ~ Scenario, data = .)) %>%
  map_dfr(~ broom::tidy(.))

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to edit my answer to more closely mirror your exact situation.  **BUT** the most likely culprit is the fact the error message says *"object 'Site' not found..."*. Since the variable is actually `Site.Year` it is strong evidence that when you grabbed my solution you failed to make that change...

Comment: fantastic, thanks Chuck! I also added df$ infront of each variable which seemed to help...

Comment: A year+ later and today I would use:    'DailyPAF_long %>% 
  group_by(Site.Year) %>% 
  group_map(~ wilcox.test(PAF ~ Scenario, data = .)) %>% 
  set_names(nm = DailyPAF_long %>% group_by(Site.Year) %>% group_keys() %>% pull()) %>% 
  purrr::imap_dfr(~ broom::tidy(.x), .id = "Site.Year")'